# Rails Arel_table Joining Several tables through a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a filter on a page by a role. So if a User is super_admin show everything else show by their role where the role matches through two tables.

User Example:

- User: John Smith
- Role: Pacific Northwest

Region Example:

- Region: Pacific Northwest
- Locations: Seattle, Portland, Boise

If John logs into see events he should only see those events that have a Location that is within the Region. So say there is an event in Portland then John would see it.

Users has_many Roles, Regions has_many Locations. Events belongs_to Location and Region but optional.

Right now this works for connecting a user's role to a region:

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |user|
 if user.super_admin?
  self
 else
  joins(:region)
   .where(Region.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{user&.role&.name}%"))
 end
}
```

So Location.name, Location.region_id = Region.id, Region.name = Role.name, Role.id = User.role_id.

I thought I could try something like:

```
joins(:location)
 .where(Location.arel_table[:region_id]).matches("%#{region.id}")
 .joins(:region)
 .where(Region.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{user&.role&.name}%"))
```

This however gives:

> Unsupported argument type: #

So given that the sortable table has Locations, and Regions. How do I filter that based on the User's role matching the Location name?

Edit:

I thought I could switch it up with the following:

```
region = Region.find_by(name: user&.role&.name)
if region.present?
 joins(:location)
  .where(location_id: region.location_ids)
end
```

This however is showing all locations. I feel like it's somewhat close. So then I tried:

```
region = Region.find_by(name: user&.role&.name)
if region.present?
 location = region.where(location_id: region.location_ids)
 return true if location.present?
end
```

That fails so I tried:

```
region = Region.find_by(name: user&.role&.name)
list_locations = []
Location.all.each.do |loc|
 list_locations << loc.name if loc.region_id == region.id && region.present?
end
self if list_location.present?
```

This ends up just showing everything.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here in case it helps someone:

```
region = Region.find_by(name: user&.role&.name)
if region.present?
 joins(:location)
  .where(location_id: region.location_ids)
end
```

This actually worked. I updated my view to show location&.region&.name and noticed that it's filtering and I just have so many pages that it appeared not to work.